# Why is `msg.mentions.users.first` causing the TypeError `member.roles.map is not a function`?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a command which lists the current roles of a user.

But when I try `` member.roles.map(roles => `${roles}`).join(', ') ``
or `message.member.roles.map(role => role.name).slice(1).join(", ")`, it throws this error:

```
TypeError: member.roles.map is not a function
    at Object.exports.run (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\commands\test.js:18:42)
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\index.js:32:14)
    at Client.emit (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\lib\events.js:388:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\Flo\Desktop\Discord_Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:376:20) {stack: 'TypeError: member.roles.map is not a function…6)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:376:20)', message: 'member.roles.map is not a function'}
```

This is the code that created this error:

```js
let user;

if (msg.mentions.users.first()) {
  user = msg.mentions.users.first();
} else {
  user = msg.author;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a log of `member.roles` please?

Comment: `member` should be an object and `roles` an array property of `member` in order to get `member.roles.map(r...` working

Answer (score 2):

Since v12, you need to add .cache before some managers like guild#members.cache & client#users.cache. All you have to do is add .cache before .map and it will work!

Read more about it here:
https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html